# error after close the application

Tags: android, opengl-es

i have a glsurfaceview renderer with some code that allows me resume after press home button and enter again on the game, and that works fine, but if i close the game with the return button, and i try enter again to the game, it crashes and close.
i've tried writing finish() on OnDestroy but not work.
i already checked that onDestroy() execute it when i press return button.
in onSurfaceCreated i have functions that load textures and set vertices for draw those textures, but, i dont understand what could be happening

edit:

this is the log after i launch the game the second time, having closed it before

```
05-08 20:30:41.069: I/GLThread(6272): noticed surfaceView surface lost tid=12
05-08 20:30:41.069: I/GLThread(6272): onResume tid=12
05-08 20:30:41.169: I/GLThread(6272): noticed surfaceView surface acquired tid=12
05-08 20:30:41.169: W/EglHelper(6272): start() tid=12
05-08 20:30:41.219: W/EglHelper(6272): createContext com.google.android.gles_jni.EGLContextImpl@4056d398 tid=12
05-08 20:30:41.219: I/GLThread(6272): noticing that we want render notification tid=12
05-08 20:30:41.219: W/GLThread(6272): egl createSurface
05-08 20:30:41.219: W/EglHelper(6272): createSurface()  tid=12
05-08 20:30:41.219: W/GLThread(6272): onSurfaceCreated
05-08 20:30:41.219: W/GLThread(6272): onSurfaceChanged(480, 320)
05-08 20:30:41.379: W/EglHelper(6272): destroySurface()  tid=12
05-08 20:30:41.389: W/EglHelper(6272): finish() tid=12
05-08 20:30:41.389: W/dalvikvm(6272): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
05-08 20:30:41.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6272): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 12
05-08 20:30:41.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6272): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 20:30:41.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6272):     at glfg.gl.render.setverticesSquare(render.java:180)
05-08 20:30:41.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6272):     at glfg.gl.render.onSurfaceChanged(render.java:475)
05-08 20:30:41.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6272):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1381)
05-08 20:30:41.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6272):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1138)
05-08 20:30:41.399: I/GLThread(6272): onPause tid=12
```

if i kill the process, i can enter again without problems, but if i exit with return button, it crashes when i try to launch it again, it's supposed that the app would be closed totally but seems that not

Comment: Noone else will understand what could be happening either, if you don't include the stack dump from your system log. Then again, if you examine it first, you might understand the problem -- but if not, edit your post to include it so someone might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
05-08 20:30:41.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6272): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 20:30:41.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6272):     at glfg.gl.render.setverticesSquare(render.java:180)
```

In glfg.gl.render.setverticesSquare at line 180. Is this part of your code? I'd look at that line and see what objects could be null, or preferably use breakpoints to inspect it.

Comment: ies render.setverticesSquare is called in onSurfaceChanged but there are nothing that could causes the error, there are no nullreferences, because, when onSurfaceChanged first i set al values to zero then, call the functions that set the vertexbuffers and textures, all that for can resume the game when home button is pressed

Comment: i've seen very well the 180 line and i saw which was the error, there was a conditional wich if is false, initialize some arrays, after that is changed to true, i have the variable evaluated in the conditional declared as:

public static boolean Conditional = false;

so i suppose that the static variables retain its values despite of have closed the app